# 42K rows ingrestion in 12 hours and still have over 70K rows waiting

Tags: python, mysql

Heads up: I'm a non-background who just learns bits from everywhere.

In a personal project, I'm building a star schema for [DWH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) on my local machine. In a fact table, I collected fields from 8 other tables (3 from [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) and 5 for [Dim tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(data_warehouse)#Dimension_table)). The main table used to ingest in the fact one has about 120K rows. Very minimal change on the logic because I want to store everything at granular level.

After a few days struggling with scripts to loading in batch (1000rows per ingest) by Python script, I finally got the hang of it. And now it comes to the next issue...it takes incredibly long to ingest 100k records with 8 tables joins. Can you share your experience with the similar situation? what I should do to ingest data faster? This kind of speed is unacceptable.

What I did? - Indexing for OLTP tables - though never tested its effectiveness . For other techniques such as filtering with conditions, partitioning, etc... I don't see any of those applicable to my case, but I can be wrong. My suspect is something lying in the hardwares' defaults that I have a very little knowledge of.

I hope I provide enough information and everything is clear. If not, please ask to clarify.

```
FactOrderItem = """
                INSERT INTO olist_olap.FactOrderItem( OrderItemID,
                                                        OrderID,
                                                        ProdKey,
                                                        SellerKey,
                                                        CustomerKey,
                                                        price,
                                                        FreightValue,
                                                        OrderStatusKey,
                                                        DateKey,
                                                        PayMethodKey,
                                                        PaymentValue,
                                                        PurchaseTimestamp,
                                                        ApprovedAt,
                                                        ShippingLimitDate,
                                                        DeliveredCarrierDate,
                                                        DeliveredCustomerDate,
                                                        EstimatedDeliverDate,
                                                        Vversion)
                SELECT 
                        CONCAT(oi.order_id, '-', oi.order_item_id) AS OrderItemID,
                        oi.order_id,
                        prod.ProdKey,
                        sell.SellerKey,
                        cust.CustomerKey,
                        oi.price,
                        oi.freight_value,
                        stat.OrderStatusKey,
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(order_purchase_timestamp)>5, DATE_FORMAT(order_purchase_timestamp, '%Y%m%d'), NULL),
                        pay.PayMethodKey,
                        paym.payment_value,
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_purchase_timestamp) > 5, CAST(ord.order_purchase_timestamp AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_approved_at) > 5, CAST(ord.order_approved_at AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(oi.shipping_limit_date) > 5, CAST(oi.shipping_limit_date AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_delivered_carrier_date) > 5, CAST(ord.order_delivered_carrier_date AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_delivered_customer_date) > 5, CAST(ord.order_delivered_customer_date AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_estimated_delivery_date) > 5, CAST(ord.order_estimated_delivery_date AS DATETIME), NULL),
                        1

                FROM olist_oltp.olist_order_items_dataset oi
                LEFT JOIN olist_oltp.olist_orders_dataset ord
                ON oi.order_id = ord.order_id
                LEFT JOIN olist_oltp.olist_order_payments_dataset paym
                ON ord.order_id = paym.order_id
                LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimCustomer cust
                ON ord.customer_id = cust.CustomerID
                LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimOrderStatus stat
                ON ord.order_status = stat.OrderStatus
                LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimProduct prod
                ON oi.product_id = prod.ProdID
                LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimSeller sell
                ON oi.seller_id = sell.SellerID
                LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimPayMethod pay
                ON paym.payment_type = pay.PaymentType
                LIMIT %s OFFSET %s;
"""
FactOrderItem_script = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olist_oltp.olist_order_items_dataset;"""
```

and this is the function I used to ingest data in batches

```
dict_fact_tables = {
    FactOrderItem_script: FactOrderItem,
    FactOrderReview_script: FactOrderReview
}

def populate_olap_tables(dic, cursor, batch_size, offset):
    """
    Function to populate the OLAP tables
    """
    for key in dic:
        cursor.execute(key)
        count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        print(count, "records found")

    # Loop through the entire table with batch size predefined
    # and offset updated
        while count > 0:
            if count < batch_size:
                batch_size = count
            try:
                cursor.execute(dic[key], (batch_size, offset))
                offset += batch_size
                count -= batch_size
                print(count, "records remaining")
                connection.commit()
            except Exception as error:
                print(f"The connection error details are: {error}")      

    print("The tables have been successfully populated.")


# Establish a connection
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )
    if connection.is_connected():
        print("Connected to the database")
    # Load the script
        batch_size = 1000
        offset = 0
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        # Count the number of records required to load in OLTP

        populate_olap_tables(dict_fact_tables, cursor, batch_size, offset)

finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        print("The connection is closed")
```

I would really appreciate any advice, sources to refer to, so I can dig deeper on this issue. I'm very curious on how large businesses manage their DWH structure given that it experiences a large amount of reads and writes concurrently.

Comment: You have provided no details of the tables or their indexes, the query with joins, the optimization report for that query, or the time that you consider unacceptable, or the time that you would consider good, or the Python code you're using to import the data. I'm afraid there's not much to go on to make recommendations for improving your task.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME 
   that includes 3 rounds of ingesting data.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I feel like this is the first step of the investigation to determine the rootcauses of slow loading? That will take me a while to figure out what they are, and how to get them. Will be back with the information you asked.

Comment: Do I see that you a using connection.commit for each row ingested?
Can you delay the commit to the end of the batch of 1000 rows?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Each loop iteration copies a "batch" of 1000 rows in one statement using `LIMIT...OFFSET`, then commits.

Comment: This post still does not include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query, which is needed to show column data types, indexes, and constraints. Also missing is the `EXPLAIN` for each query.

Comment: It would also be helpful to run `SELECT VERSION();` and show what it returns, so we know exactly what version of the DBMS software you are using. You tagged the question mysql, but what version?

Answer (score 1):

You have two big problems ATM:
your query is slow, and you don't know *which* part(s) are slow.
We'll get to those.
But first, let's tackle the trivial.

## DATE vs TEXT

You have a bunch of type CASTs like this:

```
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ord.order_purchase_timestamp) > 5, CAST(ord.order_purchase_timestamp AS DATETIME), NULL),
```

They're just an annoying distraction.
Deal with them outside of the current ETL situation.

Consider fixing up the `olist_orders_dataset` table.
There are many options.
Use ALTER COLUMN, or ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN
followed by dropping the old text column.
Or create a new table, copy rows, do a DROP and a RENAME of tables.

Or don't fix it up, just sweep the problem under the rug
with `CREATE VIEW olist_orders_dataset_v AS SELECT order_approved_at, ...`,
and bury the date expressions in there.
The conventional `_v` suffix denotes "view".

## query plans

Use EXPLAIN SELECT ... to learn what access path was chosen
by the backend planner.

Pay attention to (estimated) number of rows fetched, and
to the cost in seconds.
As you change the query, and/or do DROP / CREATE INDEX,
pay attention to how the plan changes.

It's not the easiest thing in the world to interpret a query plan.
So start small.
Use simple SELECTs, then build them up into JOINs,
and see how the planner responds.

## debugging

```
                LIMIT %s OFFSET %s;
```

That can be a great clause when serving web pages,
on the theory that a web user likely won't scroll down
to the millionth result row, so don't bother retrieving it.

But client-side loops tend to be terrible for good planning.
The client *knows* it will eventually retrieve all rows,
but it hides that knowledge from the backend planner.
If the planner knows it will fetch all rows from a table,
then a tablescan is typically the best access path,
but it can't make that decision if it can't predict
future client requests.

One good thing about that LIMIT parameter is it lets
you go through a rapid edit-run-debug cycle as you change
details of the SQL.
Reap that same benefit by testing with small tables.
For example you
could CREATE TABLE olist_orders_dataset_small AS SELECT ... ,
or you could just truncate the existing olist_orders_dataset
and then fully re-populate after you're happy with debugging.
Again, the goal is better plans.

---

Ok, on to the meat of the problem.

The current app-level throughput of about one row per second
is clearly just terrible.
There must be some hidden repeated tablescans lurking within.

## simplify

```
            LEFT JOIN olist_oltp.olist_order_payments_dataset paym ...
            LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimCustomer cust ...
            LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimOrderStatus stat ...
            LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimProduct prod ...
            LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimSeller sell ...
            LEFT JOIN olist_olap.DimPayMethod pay ...
```

Your query runs slowly.
It involves several JOINs.
You don't know which JOIN(s) are slow.

Delete them all.

Whittle down the query to the bare minimum,
and see it run quickly.
An INSERT ... SELECT ... should be able to
move more than ten thousand rows per second.
When you start asking it to do fancy things, it will slow down.
For now we will just insert default NULL column variables where an
[FK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) value belongs.

Read and understand this performant EXPLAIN SELECT query plan.

Now start adding those JOINs back, one by one.
Or, roughly equivalently, populate columns one by one
with UPDATE ... JOIN.
Pay attention to the timings, and (for slow operations) to the plans.
Maybe you're missing a
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key#Design) index?
Every table should have a sensible PK.
Every FK relationship should be supported by foreign table's index,
which almost always will be foreign table's PK.

## put it all together

By this point you have learned something about how to work
*with* (not *against*) the planner, to rapidly access your favorite rows.
Query times are now predictable, and are faster than before.
You may have changed how you index tables.
Even with multiple JOINs, you should be able to
query more than a thousand rows per second.
Your git repo has seen more than a few edits of SQL commands.

In a new schema, issue some DROP TABLEs to tear it all down,
then run your DDL which defines tables + indexes,
then run a single query to populate FactOrderItem.